# Windows equivalent of find -cmin +24

Tags: command-prompt

What would be the windows (command prompt) equivalent of the following command?

```
find -cmin +24 | xargs rm
```

This command finds all files with "status changed over 24 minutes ago", and then removes them.

It is suggested in the php.ini config file as a way to clear old session files, but my server is a windows system.

I've found out that 'dir' has the /T:A option, but that only gets me so far.. How would I delete the files older than 24 minutes?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this isn't in command, if you've got Powershell on the machine, the following script will work.

```
$oldest = [system.datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-1)
# Directory to clean up
$directory = "C:\Temp\test2"

# This lists the files it would delete
dir $directory | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $oldest}

# Uncomment this line to delete them
#dir $directory | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt $oldest} | erase
```

Comment: It works! Just a bit unfortunate that it's powershell, but I can handle it :-) Thanks!